# CSS: How can I address specific classes only when within specific class?

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I'm trying to address *flex-control-nav*, *flex-control-paging* and *flex-direction-nav* - but only, when they're within *fusion-recent-posts*. Tinkering since hours but haven't found a solution yet, that doesn't also affects other sliders.

[image]

Hoping somebody here might be able to help me out?

Comment: `.fusion-recent-posts .flex-control-nav { ...your styles... }`

Comment: Please see my answer below. It is always better to post your question with code examples of what you tried instead of a screenshot, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular CSS, here it is:

```
.fusion-recent-posts .flex-control-nav {
  // your styles
}

.fusion-recent-posts .flex-control-paging {
  // your styles
}

.fusion-recent-posts .flex-direction-nav {
  // your styles
}
```